# Tomcat - Move database connection out of server.xml

Tags: tomcat, persistence, datasource, jndi, tomcat8

I am on tomcat 8 and so far the database connection (resource) is configured in `conf/server.xml`

```
<Resource name="jdbc/onejndi"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxTotal="8"
          maxIdle="30"
          maxWaitMillis="10000"
          username="sa"
          password=""
          driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
          url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:c:/.../>
```

In the applications `META-INF/context.xml` we have the corresponding resourcelink

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/onejndi" global="jdbc/onejndi"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Now i am supposed to move the db connection out of the global server.xml.
Putting everything in the applications `META-INF/context.xml` is problematic, as the application will be run in different stages with different databases and we will not be able to provide specific builds for every stage.

Do have have an idea, a hint, ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i have found the solution myself.

I place a file `context.xml.default` inside `tomcat/conf/catalina/localhost`.
Structured like a standard context.xml-file and may contain resource-tags like in server.xml.

Now i do neither need to change files of the baseline tomcat nor write database connections in the applications META-INF/context.xml.

side note:

- context.xml.default => is available for all applications
- myapp.xml => is availbe only for the app with the name "myapp"

Answer (score 1):

Keep your existing global `server.xml` and `/MATA-INF/context.xml` unchanged, add the following JNDI in the web application 's `/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/onejndi</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Then in your application codes , you can access the DB connection pool by `java:comp/env/jdbc/onejndi`.

This is not problematic as the JNDI name `jdbc/onejndi` in `MATA-INF/context.xml` and `/WEB-INF/web.xml` are the same for all environments.The DB connection properties (hostname , username , password etc.) which are different across each environment can be configured in  `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` which is not packaged inside the WAR.

That means you can build the WAR once and deploy to different environments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is, that the database connection is different for every stage and if the properties are placed in the ``META-INF/context.xml`` a new package/build is necessary.

Comment: You mean the DB connection properties such as hostname, password , username etc?  They can be put directly in the server 's `/conf/server.xml` which is not packed in the WAR. The `META-INF/context.xml` in the WAR does not contain any DB connection info , only JNDI name which is the same for all environment

Comment: @KenChan This is exactly as the Java EE designers envisioned deployments: the WAR file contains a reference to some externally-defined JNDI resource, and the JNDI resource is defined concretely by the server (in `conf/server.xml` in Tomcat's case).

Comment: Yes, you're right. But as i mentioned i have to get db-configuration out of tomcats server.xml - system admins want their "baseline tomcats" to be unchanged.